# Initiate and exit several pipenv environments with a bash script

Tags: python, bash, pipenv

I have an ETL pipeline and I would like to start it using a bash script. Each of these proceses are in different folders and have different pipenv environment each, I wonder what would be the way to start one of the environments and then close it to then open the next pipenv environment, etc.

For example the first one would be:

```
pipenv run python tweepy_ingestion/main.py
```

But how do I exit it to go to the other folder and open the other pipenv environment there? Let's say another directory with this path `./spark_app/spark_app.py`, should I exit the pipenv first and then use the `pipenv run python` with the file or how?

Comment: What do you mean by "exit the pipenv"? When you use the `pipenv run` command, you're not persistently activating the virtual environment -- it's only active for the duration of the command. When it exits, you can just `cd` to a different directory and start a new `pipenv run` command.

Comment: oh, great that simply things, I didn't know that